# Accessing remote html file using Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, parsing

I have a html page stored remotely, How can I access using Reactjs ? if I can able to access then how I can parse that page and render in browser ? can any one faced this kind of challenge, please let me know the solutions if you found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fetch API to download and render the page.

```
    fetch("http://www.example.com/home.html") 
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((html) => { document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html; })
.catch((error) => { console.warn(error); });
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it wont work as i was tried.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching can be done with `fetch("http://example.com/path/to/file.html")` - this returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

If you want to use the fetched html page inside of react, you can fetch it, save it in the state and then render it using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property on a div - check out [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r79kwl7p4).